# Sub directory within a sub directory

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I would like a batch/powershell script to create the below tree structure in a the main folder. The script shall be run from the main folder which is the parent directory to create the below structure.

- Folder ABC
- Folder DEF
- Folder GHI

  - Folder GHIN

    - Folder N1
    - Folder N2
    - Folder N3

Since it's my first time trying scripting, I only got to this point:

```
@echo off

md "FOLDER ABC" "FOLDER DEF" "FOLDER GHI"\"FOLDER GHIN"\"FOLDER N1"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many, many better ways of doing this, but since you asked and barely tried, we will leave the actual automating up to you:

```
Function Make-MyFolders()
{
    Set-Location C:\users\myusername\desktop
    $parentFolders = @("Folder ABC","Folder DEF","Folder GHI")
    $firstChildFolders = @("Folder GHIN")
    $secondChildFolders = @("Folder N1", "Folder N2", "Folder N3")

    foreach($parent in $parentFolders)
    {
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Name $parent
    }

    Set-Location -Path '.\Folder GHI'

    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Name $firstChildFolders[0]

    Set-Location -Path '.\Folder GHIN'

    foreach($item in $secondChildFolders)
    {
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Name $item
    }
}

Make-MyFolders
```

Answer (score 2):

In PowerShell `New-Item` automatically creates missing parent folders, so all you need is a list with the unique longest paths.

```
$folders = 'Folder ABC',
           'Folder DEF',
           'Folder GHI\Folder GHIN\Folder N1',
           'Folder GHI\Folder GHIN\Folder N2',
           'Folder GHI\Folder GHIN\Folder N3'

New-Item -Type Directory $folders
```

Comment: Didn't know that one Ansgar, thanks for the pro-tip!